# Динамическое наполнение словаря в python

Tags: python, json

Добрый день, подскажите как наполнять словарь в цикле?
Пример: `json = {"atr":[{"item1":value1},{"item2":value2},...,{itemN:valueN}]}`
И потом соединить с этим словарем:

```
json2 = {"auth" : {"login" : "","psw" : ""},"key" : "", "pers":""}
```

Answer (score 2):

Сам разобрался, мб еще кому-то пригодится))

```
json = {"atr":[]}
for i in range(3):
    json['atr'].append({"name":name+str(i), "value":i})
json2.update(json)
```

Comment: к сожелению к json этот вопрос с ответом не имеет никакого отношения....